# designing flexible page layout

Tags: css, css-float

first see the image prepared in paint.

[image]

I want to design a flexible page which will have this type of four division. and hence change in monitor screen or browser size re-sizes window automatically. This all 4 box should fit 100% browser screen and any monitor size and avoiding scroll bar to appear ever. so can any one tell me how to code it in css stylesheet.

here is my code.
html:

```
<div id="bottomleft">
</div>

<div id="topleft">
</div>

<div id="topright">
</div>

<div id="bottomright">
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
    *
    {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    #wrapper
    {
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
    #bottomleft
    {
    position:relative;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    }
    #topleft
    {
    position:relative;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: right;
    }
    #topright
    {
    position:relative;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    }
    #bottomright
    {
    position:relative;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: right;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/CLe6z/1/)***

HI now define your `body, html height 100%;` in css as like this

and define `box-sizing` in your `id`

```
body, html{
height:100%;
}
#bottomleft, #bottomright, #topright, #topleft{
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/CLe6z/1/)***

Comment: can you tell me weather my css code(specifying height,width to 50%) is really needed?

Comment: actually you have to define the parent's height so that's why @Rohit defined the height of body, html......

Comment: yup got it now. How it works.? thanks for getting me started. :)

Answer (score 0):

You use this meta in head tag for all device and use other css for any window width

this meta use for any devic and link tag for load css with min-width شrbitrary

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print and (min-width: 25cm)" href="http://…" />
```

best regards